# Rolling n-day aggregation conditional on another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

struggling to figure out how to implement a code that will allow me to calculate following (using SQL in BigQuery) in an elegant way.

I'd need to calculate a rolling n-day aggregation (let's assume rolling 3-day sum of units ) for each date but only taking into account data that where the price is less than a certain value (let's assume 50).

So based on below table

| date | price | units |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-21 | 30 | 200 |
| 01-22 | 100 | 500 |
| 01-23 | 20 | 200 |
| 01-24 | 20 | 100 |
| 01-25 | 80 | 100 |
| 01-26 | 40 | 250 |

I'd need my query to return:

| date | units |
| --- | --- |
| 01-21 | 200 |
| 01-22 | 200 |
| 01-23 | 400 |
| 01-24 | 300 |
| 01-25 | 300 |
| 01-26 | 350 |

Struggling to figure out how to combine window calculations with the additional conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select date, sum(if(price < 50, units, 0)) over win units
from your_table
window win as (order by unix_date(date) range between 2 preceding and current row)
```

if applied to sample data as in your question -

```
with your_table as (
  select date '2022-01-21' date, 30 price, 200 units union all
  select '2022-01-22', 100, 500 union all
  select '2022-01-23', 20, 200 union all
  select '2022-01-24', 20, 100 union all
  select '2022-01-25', 80, 100 union all
  select '2022-01-26', 40, 250 
)
```

the output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer indeed solves my simplified issue but I realised that my dataframe is too different after all.

Comment: if it solved - consider accepting then! and post new question and we will help you further!